# iOS description method not called

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I've overridden the description method of an object I created, quite simple. This object is a subclass of `NSMutableURLRequest`.

```
- (NSString *)description
{
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

I also put `- (NSString *)description;` in the .h

But it is not called when I `NSLog` the object. It is not a `NSManagedObject`. Even the debugger won't step into "description" if I only call `myObject.description;`. I am calling the method precisely on an instance of my object, not just a `NSMutableURLRequest`.

EDIT: 
I instantiate the object like this:

```
MYRequest *myRequest = [MYRequest requestWithFilter:myFilter];

NSLog(@"%@", myRequest);
```

And here is the factory method:

```
@interface MYRequest : NSMutableURLRequest
+ (instancetype)requestWithFilter:(NSString *)filter;


@implementation MYRequest
+ (instancetype)requestWithFilter:(NSString *)filter
{
    // some config
    MYRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:0 timeoutInterval:15];
    // some more config
    return request;
}
```

What the heck?

Comment: ``NSMutableURLRequest`` or ``NSURLRequest`` classes doesn't have ``- (NSString *)description`` method declared. You are accessing ``NSObject``'s method ``- (NSString *)description``. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#jumpTo_7)

Comment: Show the code where you instantiate the object.

Comment: As Kevin said in his answer, you are instantiating an NSMutableURLRequest, not your subclass.

Comment: @Jasarien oh, yea obviously, got it! thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an instance of your subclass, you just have a normal `NSMutableURLRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableURLRequest` or `NSURLRequest` classes doesn't have `- (NSString *)description` method declared.

You are accessing `NSObject`'s method `- (NSString *)description`.

See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#jumpTo_7)

You should declare **your own** `description` method in your custom class and call it like:

`NSString *myObjectDescription = [myCustomObject description];`